# How may I use selnolig for a bilingual document?

Tags: selnolig

The great package `selnolig` offers support for the English or the German language. Maybe I have overseen it, but is there a possibility to change the language-option inside the document?

The best way would be to let it change by the macros of `polyglossia`.

Please see my MWE and the two images!

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setdefaultlanguage[%
    ,babelshorthands=true
    ]{german}
\setotherlanguage[%
    ,variant = british
    ]{english}
\usepackage[%
    %,german
    ,english
    ]{selnolig}

\begin{document}
\noindent Auftakt, halftime\\
\begin{english}
Auftakt, halftime
\end{document}
```

`german`-option enabled:
[image]

`english`-option enabled:
[image]

**Edit**

It is possible to load both options and to get the correct result for my example. But I guess that there will be clashes between the rules (can't think of an example at the moment). Especially for the future version of `selnolig` which provides hyphenation rules as well. So my question could also be: Does `selnolig` recognize the current language when both local options are loaded? A `babel` solution would be fine, too, but I understand that I should use `polyglossia` with LuaLaTeX.

**Edit 2**

As can be seen in my new images, the answer to my last question is "no". The package searches for German/English words over the whole document ignoring the current language environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I honestly don't know how to achieve your objective via `polyglossia`'s macros and options. I'd simply use the instruction

```
\usepackage[german,english]{selnolig}
```

in the preamble. Doing so enables *both sets* of selective ligature suppression rules. At this time, the package doesn't offer a method for disabling just one set of language rules once they've been loaded.

I'm aware of just a couple of conflicts between the package's German and English ligature suppression rules. Fortunately, these conflicts arise only if the rather pedantic [!] `broadf` option is enabled on the English-language side. E.g., the rule `\nolig{ffing}{ff|ing}` -- relevant for words such as ruffing and bluffing -- will inappropriately break up the `fi` ligature in the German words `fünffingrig` and `Zwölffingerdarm`. To overcome this conflict, one could provide the additional rules `\keeplig{ffingrig}` and `\keeplig{ffinger}`. (Not to worry, selnolig's rules that suppress the `ff` ligature in `fünffingrig` and `Zwölffingerdarm` are *not* affected by the provision of these additional `\keeplig` rules.) Aside: I may well drop the `broadf` option and the associated ligature suppression rules in a future version of `selnolig`.

The package does let you suspend its operations *locally* via a `\uselig{...}` instruction or *globally* via the directive `\selnoligoff` (and resume operations via `\selnoligon`). However, there's currently no option to suspend (or re-enable) just the German or just the English language-related rules -- let alone make the suspension and resumption of these rules depend on which language is the main or default language. I'd be curious to get any real-world feedback from users who need bilingual support and think this is an issue that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I'll try to mind the word Zwölffingerdarm in my report. Thank you Mico!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi - By the way, many thanks for the compliment about the "great" package!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi - I just an overlap between the rule `\nolig{fless}{f|less}` (for words such as `selfless`) -- which is in the "basic", not the "broadf", group of rules -- and `Mohnflesserl`. Just in case your documents contain that word...

Comment: Damn, the title is "Indigestion in the Duodenum due to Poppy Pastries." I fear, this makes your tool worthless for my work.